# $(document).ready() firing immediately within a jQuery-AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, document-ready, ready

I have an html page called `search.html` that contains the following jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...some code // THIS IS THE CODE I'M INTERESTED IN
}
...some other code
```

And I have another html page that contains the following jQuery code:

```
$("#display_area").load("search.html") // #display_area is a div
```

The problem is, when this jQuery code is called, it inserts the content of `search.html` but executes the code that I'm interested in (the code in the $(document).ready() section) immediately, it doesn't wait for the DOM to be ready, which obviously generates errors.

The other codes (outside the  $(document).ready() section) execute normally without any problems.

Placing the code within the callback function of the .load() function doesn't work either, the code fires while the DOM isn't ready.

Is there any way to solve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT : I just want to specify, that the `search.html` contains a DOM of its own that is going to be inserted in the #display_area div, and I want my code to fire when the #display_area div has finished loading all its new DOM (content) that was loaded through the load() function.

Comment: are you able to edit `search.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your mistake is that `$(document).ready` is called when your main page's DOM is ready the first time. Changing the DOM doesn't re-fire `$(document).ready`. Your confusion comes from the fact that you call `$("#display_area").load("search.html")` when the page loads. At that time, the original DOM is not finished yet, when it is, `$(document).ready` is fired, later (at some random moment) your Ajax function returns. And that's it.

To execute code *after* your Ajax .load function returns, use this

```
$("#display_area").load("search.html", function() { 
    alert('New DOM elements should be available now'); 
    // do more stuff 
} );
```

Edit: OK, so here's the whole scheme:

- In your main html page, call `$("#display_area").load("search.html")` only when the DOM is ready. So do this call from a `$(document).ready` function *in your main page*
- Next, use the callback function of .load as I described, do whatever you want in there
- Finally, if you want code in search.html to be executed after it is loaded: agree upon a function name between your main page and search.html. This function is defined in search.html and called from the .load callback.

Comment: Thank you for your help but as I said in the question, placing the code within the callback function of .load(), just like you did, doesn't work either. The code in the callback function executes even when the #display_area div didn't finish updating its DOM. I'm deeply convinced it is a problem with the DOM being not ready because if I reload the page several times, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Ah. Then do the .load call inside the document.ready of the main page!  Also, I will make a small edit to explain and add something.

Comment: Thank you, but still doesn't work. Actually it seems that the problem is with the load function. I removed all code from the $(document).ready - now there is no more $(document).ready in my called page -  and placed it within the callback function of load(). I called the load() function only when the DOM of mainpage is ready as you suggested and the code within the callback function still launches too early.

Comment: Your observation contradicts with the jQuery API: 'If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.' So we must be missing something, somewhere. Do you know how to debug network requests? This is a little different per browser, Chrome: ctrl-shift-J then click network. What happens exactly? Does the search.html become part of the #display_area div eventually? Is this or is this not visible yet when the .load alert box appears?

Comment: I'm sorry, the way I did it in the beginning with $(document).ready() was as you and @logansama suggested, wrong for sure. But even though I put all the code in the callback function of load() it didn't work but pointing out that according to jQuery API it must work put me on the right track and it turned out it wasn't working because of another problem : I have a jQuery slider UI that is loaded among this code and it seems to not work when loaded through AJAX and since it is in the beginning of the code, it was preventing all the rest from running too. Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

$(document).ready() in search.html will fire off when search.html is loaded, which will occur when .load() is done, even if the other page is not done loading.

You could try placing the JS code on search.html in a normal function and then in the callback function of .load() you call this 'newly added' function. Populating the div can still occur in the .load() callback function.

Comment: Thank you for your help but as I said in the question and in my comment to @Jochem, placing the code within the callback function of .load(), just like you explained, doesn't work either. The code in the callback function executes even when the #display_area div didn't finish updating its DOM. I'm deeply convinced it is a problem with the DOM being not ready because if I reload the page several times, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou - what you can then add to my answer is to place the .load(..) within a .ready() of the other file. That should then load the DOM with your container div before loading search.html etc.